# How can I overwrite a core laravel method?

Tags: php, oop, laravel

Here is what I'm trying to do:

We are using `Laravel 4.2` in our project, and are using the frameworks' `Password::remind` functionality to send emails for password reset.

The problem is that the team wants all the email templates to be located inside the database instead of the `views` folder, so I will have to somehow pass a string to the `Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\PasswordBroker::sendReminder` method.

How can I override this class in Laravel so I can make this thing work? I'm currently a Laravel newbie so I don't yet fully understand how the framework works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't easy to override the classes simply. Whole laravel mail is based on views. But you can probably create a workaround to achieve you're goal.

For this you've to make the required views. In a service provider or in you're route file you make a view composer. With that view composer you retrieve your data from the database and the only thing you do in the view is printing the value.

```
View::composer(array('reminders.password','reminders.other'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('html', RemindersRepository::getHtml());
});
```

Or something like that. Now in you're view print {{$html}} and it works!

Edit:
For you're information a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers) is something like a event listener. When the view is loaded, the callback function of the composer is loaded. In that callback function you can pass a extra variable with some contents. In the view you can print this value added in the composer.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, this allows me to create a view from string?

Comment: This worked like a charm in my case :) If only now we could make it work without having to keep an empty file in the views folder that would be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic guide on how to override/extend core functionality in Laravel:

You can create a folder in `app/start/` and then create your own class to override the default behavior like `NewReminderServiceProvider.php` Then you extend the core functionality in question:

```
class NewReminderServiceProvider extends Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider {}
```

then overwrite or extend the `registerPasswordBroker`.

In the parent you are extending, you will see where it sets the view:

```
$view = $app['config']['auth.reminder.email'];
```

change that to be database driven however you want.

then last of all you have to swap out the `ReminderServiceProvider` with your `NewReminderServiceProvider` in your `app/config/app.php` and you are good to go. This will work with almost any core functionality. Replace or extend blade, auth, etc.